# Comparing a Cucumber Data Table to Ruby Array of Hashes

Tags: ruby, cucumber, hashtable

I am trying to compare data from a cucumber table to an array of hashes.

```
 Cucumber step: 

 Then I expect tasks created with:
      | issuetype | summary       | status | 
      | Task      | Please review | To do  | 
      | Task      | Please review | To do  |
```

I turned the table into a hash using:

```
Then (/^I expect tasks created with:/) do |table| 
  table = table.hashes
end 


 [{"issuetype"=>"Task", 
   "summary"=>"Please review", 
   "status"=>"To do", 
   "assignee"=>"unassigned", 
   "assigned group"=>"rm-group1"}, 
  {"issuetype"=>"Task", 
   "summary"=>"Please review", 
   "status"=>"To do", 
   "assignee"=>"unassigned", 
   "assigned group"=>"rm-group2"}]
```

How can I select the values (`issuetype`, `summary`, `status`) from the data underneath, which is is a JSON  parse and  format it like the `table.hashes` above and compare them?

```
tasks [ {
      id: 1
      fields:{ 
           summary: "Summary"
      } 
           status:{
                 description: "description"
                 currentstatus: "To do"
             }
            issuetype{ 
                  id: "5"
                  name: "sub-task"
             }
           }]
```

Comment: Please show how `table.hashes` looks like.

Comment: @mudasobwa I have just included it in the code block

Answer (score 0):

I expect the `table.hashes` to be:

```
[
  { issuetype: 'Task', summary: 'Please review', status: 'To do' },
  { issuetype: 'Task 2', summary: 'Please review', status: 'To do' },
]
```

To get the array of hashes to compare out of your `tasks` (which is apparently an invalid object, hence I was forced to make an assumption on it’s real structure:

```
mapped = tasks.map do |hash|
  {
    issuetype: hash[:issuetype][:name],
    summary: hash[:fields][:summary],
    status: hash[:status][:currentstatus]
  }
end
```

Now it’s fine to compare `table.hashes` and `mapped`. **NB** the solution above assumes hash keys are *symbols*. Whether they are strings, the respective cast is to be done.

Comment: In this way I do not select the values right? In case the table is expanded with more columns, I would have to rewrite tasks.map.

Comment: I am not sure I understood this question. Values are compared altogether with keys. When one has more columns, one should _append_ these columns to `map`.